# How to apply regular expression in urdu text using python

Tags: python, regex, tweepy

I want to apply a regular expression to eliminate English characters numbers and symbols in Urdu text. I am extracting tweets from Twitter in Urdu and I want to remove everything besides Urdu and emojis.

This is my output

```
;00;RT @MeFixerr: شہباز شریف صاحب اس 
لگن سے جھوٹ پہ جھوٹ بول رہے ہیں جیسے 
اسمبلی پاکستان کی نہیں اسپین کی 
ہو جہاں کسی کو اردو نہیں آتی
```

this is my code

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q="اردو", rpp=10).items(10):
    msg = [tweet.text] 
    msg = tuple(msg)                    
    msgs.append(msg)
    df = pd.DataFrame(msgs)
    df.to_csv('ae3214.txt', sep = ';', line_terminator = '', encoding = 'UTF-8')
```

Comment: One way can be to only keep the range of Unicode char those represent Urdu. 
I've created a regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/g1sjLc/1). It's just a starting point you can create a more sophisticated regex to handle special cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `flags=re.UNICODE`

**Ex:**

```
import re
s = """;00;RT @MeFixerr: شہباز شریف صاحب اس 
لگن سے جھوٹ پہ جھوٹ بول رہے ہیں جیسے 
اسمبلی پاکستان کی نہیں اسپین کی 
ہو جہاں کسی کو اردو نہیں آتی """

print(re.sub(r"[A-Za-z0-9@;:]", "", s, flags=re.UNICODE))    #Replaces English letters, numbers and symbols like @;:
```